# Problem displaying all photos with api in php select query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to display the images from api in a card that takes data from the base mysql with php

The following code shows me only the photo of the first php project with api. I would like to show a photo for all 12 records with. Anyone can help

Thanks **to propose a solution**

*php code and jquery is below*

```
<?php
$q = "SELECT  *  FROM movies
INNER JOIN includes ON includes.mid=movies.mid
INNER JOIN genre ON includes.gid=genre.gid
WHERE genre.gid=1 AND movies.year>0
ORDER BY movies.year DESC LIMIT 12";
$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);
$numr = mysqli_num_rows($r);

if ($numr > 0) 
{ // αν υπάρχουν εγγραφές...
$check=1;}
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)) { 
echo"
<div  class='col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 col-12'>
<div class='card2'>
  <div class='card'>
    
     <div class='col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2'>
         <div class='pretty_movie_output'></div>
     </div>
     
  
     <div class='card-block'>
      <h6 id='title' class='card-title'>".$row['mtitle']."</h6>
      <p><i class='fa fa-star-o' style='color:#dcf836'></i><span>".$row['rating']."</span> /10</p> 
      <p id='year'>".$row['year']."</p>   
   
    </div>
    <div class='card-block'>
       
      <a href='#' class='btn btn-primary btn-block'>Read more</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
";
      }
   ?>

        and jquery ajax code
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
        //Gather values from the other fields and store them into variables.
           var title = $("#title").text();
           var year = $("#year").val();
        // Concatenate those variables to a query string.
        
        var queryString = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=&t=" + title + "&y=" + year + "&plot=short&r=json";
        // Put that query string into the AJAX request
     
      $.ajax({
            url: queryString, 
            method: 'GET'
            
        }).done(function(response) {
        
            if(response.length < 1) {
            
                // Output error message into output container
                $("#output").html("Sorry, no movies were found :(");
            } else {
                // Output data into output container
                
               $("#output").html(JSON.stringify(response[prop]));
            

                // create an HTML element that will hold all of the prettified elements
                var card= $('<div class="card">');
                // Append the movie container to the existing container
                   $(".pretty_movie_output").append(card);
               

                // Go through each property of the object and create/input the data from the 
   object
                for(var prop in response) {
                 
                    var element;
                    if (prop == "Poster" && response[prop] != "N/A") {
                        element = $("<img class='pretty'>").attr("src", response[prop]);
                
                    } 
         
                    card.append(element);
                }
                
            }
            
          
        });
         
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you clarify how this is supposed to work - how does the jQuery code that fetches data from a remote website and the PHP generated content shown above relate to one another? The PHP above looks correct and should display 12 results ~ do you have at least 12 results in your database?

Comment: Yes I have correctly 12 records that the title is presented correctly, rating, what I try to do is when the page loads to pass the photos of the documents via api because they do not exist in my database. The jquery code shows me a photo of only the first registration via api, reading from the registration title and year. I try to make all twelve photos appear

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.